# Oracle Join two table with timestamp condition with + OR - INTERVAL 30 SeC

Tags: oracle, join, oracle11g, timestamp

I have 2 tables
TableA.TimeStamp
TableB.CreateTIME

Most of they time they are equal sometime they are off by less than 60 seconds.

I need to create a join and also include condition that it is ok if they are 60 seconds off from each other

```
SELECT TableA.Blah,TableB.Blah
FROM TableA TableA on TableB.CreateTime = TableA.TimeStamp
```

Comment: If you do a join on Table A and Table B on the TimeStamp/CreateTIME columns, then your result set will only be that of when TimeStamp/CreateTIME are equal. Therefore there will not be any difference in seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ABS` with date conversion and comparison.  Usually date math works best with the `INTERVAL` syntax, but not in this case because `ABS` doesn't work with intervals.

```
create table TableA(id number, TimeStamp timestamp);
create table TableB(id number, CreateTIME timestamp);

insert into TableA values (1, timestamp '2000-01-01 00:00:00');
insert into TableA values (2, timestamp '2000-01-01 00:00:30');
insert into TableB values (3, timestamp '2000-01-01 00:00:45');
insert into TableB values (4, timestamp '2000-01-01 00:00:59');

select TableA.id a_id, TableB.id b_id
from TableA
join TableB
  on abs(cast(TableA.TimeStamp as date)-cast(TableB.CreateTIME as date)) < 30/(24*60*60);

A_ID   B_ID
----   ----
2      3
2      4
```

Here's a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7d107/1).